# Inkscape drawn SVG circle isn't rendered on firefox or image viewers

Tags: inkscape, render-settings

I have a weird problem where SVG circles don't show up anywhere from image viewer to firefox or chrome!

Here are the things I did:

1. I have drawn a simple check mark with a circle:
   [image]

I also drew another one:
[image]

2. Now I am trying to put that in my webpage! But if I open my file manager, I see this:

[image]

On viewnior image viewer:
[image]

And same thing on firefox:

[image]

What could be wrong with my art?

Edit:
Code for the stroked check svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="147.41847mm"
   height="148.39937mm"
   viewBox="0 0 147.41847 148.39937"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1915"
   inkscape:version="1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15, custom)"
   sodipodi:docname="check.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1909" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.49497475"
     inkscape:cx="277.80728"
     inkscape:cy="347.97113"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata1912">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-54.802666,-51.28841)">
    <g
       id="g1894"
       transform="matrix(0.3527778,0,0,0.3527778,38.200788,35.176978)">
      <path
         style="fill:#00aa00;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="m 369.16406,174.76913 c 7.8125,7.8125 7.8125,20.47656 0,28.28516 L 234.99219,337.23006 c -7.8125,7.80859 -20.47485,7.81078 -28.28516,0 l -63.87109,-63.87499 c -7.8125,-7.8086 -7.8125,-20.47266 0,-28.28125 7.80859,-7.8125 20.47265,-7.8125 28.28125,0 l 49.73047,49.73046 120.03125,-120.03515 c 7.8125,-7.80859 20.47656,-7.80859 28.28515,0 z"
         id="path7-6" />
      <circle
         style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00aa00;stroke-width:37.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="path1867"
         sodipodi:type="arc"
         sodipodi:cx="256"
         sodipodi:cy="256"
         sodipodi:rx="190.25674"
         sodipodi:ry="191.69719"
         sodipodi:start="5.3377585"
         sodipodi:end="5.3377573"
         sodipodi:open="true"
         sodipodi:arc-type="arc"
         d="M 367.37571,100.58211 A 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 410.25009,368.21889 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 144.62438,411.41796 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 101.74984,143.7812 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 367.37552,100.58197" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Code for the filled svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="147.41847mm"
   height="148.39937mm"
   viewBox="0 0 147.41847 148.39937"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1915"
   inkscape:version="1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15, custom)"
   sodipodi:docname="check-filled.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1909" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="331.79701"
     inkscape:cy="381.40473"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata1912">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-54.802666,-51.28841)">
    <g
       id="g1894"
       transform="matrix(0.3527778,0,0,0.3527778,38.200788,35.176978)">
      <circle
         style="fill:#00aa00;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00aa00;stroke-width:37.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;fill-opacity:1"
         id="path1867"
         sodipodi:type="arc"
         sodipodi:cx="256"
         sodipodi:cy="256"
         sodipodi:rx="190.25674"
         sodipodi:ry="191.69719"
         sodipodi:start="5.3377585"
         sodipodi:end="5.3377573"
         sodipodi:open="true"
         sodipodi:arc-type="arc"
         d="M 367.37571,100.58211 A 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 410.25009,368.21889 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 144.62438,411.41796 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 101.74984,143.7812 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 367.37552,100.58197" />
      <path
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         d="m 369.16406,174.76913 c 7.8125,7.8125 7.8125,20.47656 0,28.28516 L 234.99219,337.23006 c -7.8125,7.80859 -20.47485,7.81078 -28.28516,0 l -63.87109,-63.87499 c -7.8125,-7.8086 -7.8125,-20.47266 0,-28.28125 7.80859,-7.8125 20.47265,-7.8125 28.28125,0 l 49.73047,49.73046 120.03125,-120.03515 c 7.8125,-7.80859 20.47656,-7.80859 28.28515,0 z"
         id="path7-6" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: offhand.. perhaps "Stroke width: 37.5...4" ?

Comment: It's actually an ellipsis put by firefox to prevent long lines, the actual code is: `style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00aa00;stroke-width:37.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"`

Comment: Mainly because of your namespace definition. I mean your svg has all sorts of nonvalid svg in it

Comment: I'm using Archlinux and the inkscape came straight out of the Archlinux x86-64's repo. I haven't made any changes to the SVG by hand, or I think I haven't messed up any settings. Could it be some specific settings that's generating these bad codes with lots of polyfills?

Comment: Yeah you shouldnt just save the file you should export it without inkscape code. Simply the circle isnt valid svg

Comment: Yup. But anway, the problem is fixed by selecting the circle, and choosing "Object to Path": https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4989

Comment: Or just use the plain svg option, i wouldnt convert circles to paths honestly. Just dont save inkscape svg.

Comment: When saving from Inkscape use the file type "Plain SVG", or "Optimized SVG".  An Inkscape SVG contains Inkscape specific markup which isn't required, and could potentially cause problems.

Comment: @S.Goswami: Which version of Inkscape are you using?

Comment: Hi, it's Inkscape 1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15, custom)

Comment: @S.Goswami: As a workaround: export the drawing to PDF. Then Import it again in Inkscape and save it as SVG (Inkscape SVG, or other variants). I have tested that, and the final output looks fine.

Comment: @S.Goswami: Could you please report this issue here https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues? I am pretty sure this will get fixed.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have reported the issue, it was closed and turns out the developers are already working to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that, for some weird reason, the svg circle is wrong. I converted to path and I have obtained a two concentric circles conforming the circle. Just as if it was made out of two concentric circles using the exclusion option.

This svg code is correctly shown on Viewnior and Firefox:

```
<svg xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="147mm" height="149mm" viewBox="0 0 147 149">

<path style="fill:#00aa00;" d="M 74.1,0 C 33.1,0 0,33.4 0,74.8 0,116 33.1,149 74.1,149 114,149 147,116 147,74.8 147,33.4 114,0 74.1,0 Z m 0,13.2 C 107,13.2 134,40.5 134,74.8 134,108 107,136 74.1,136 40.1,136 13.2,108 13.2,74.8 13.2,40.5 40.1,13.2 74.1,13.2 Z M 113,45.8 c 3,2.8 3,7 0,10 L 66.1,103 c -3,3 -7,3 -10,0 L 33.8,80.8 c -2.8,-3 -2.8,-7 0,-10 2.8,-3 7,-3 9.9,0 l 17.4,17 42.9,-42 c 2,-2.8 7,-2.8 9,0 z"/>
</svg>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I just edited the answer to provide an optimized unique path svg.

Comment: I don't think this is the actual source of the problem. You don't have to convert SVG circles or ellipses to paths.  I think the problem is that you are trying to use the Inkscape SVG, i.e. the one with the sodipodi in the XML.  This can cause problems.  Also there's no need for that thick stroke, just do a circle with a fill and no stroke. Save as Optimized SVG instead. You'll get something like this: https://svgshare.com/i/iXK.svg - the SVG circle renders perfectly fine in Firefox.

Comment: @BillyKerr I just noticed this circle code, on the posted question, is completely wrong, then tried to find a solution. This is the wrong code:  `<circle style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#00aa00;stroke-width:37.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" d="M 367.37571,100.58211 A 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 410.25009,368.21889 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 144.62438,411.41796 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 101.74984,143.7812 190.25674,191.69719 0 0 1 367.37552,100.58197" />`

Comment: You may leave or delete the sodopodi part as it is irrelevant for browser rendering. But need to change the tag circle for path as the properties provided in there are those for path and not for circle. That sintax is wrong.

Comment: yes the code is wrong, it's a path.  But Inkscape should generate a properly formed SVG circle. See the SVG I linked to. This was generated by Inkscape. I redrew the circle. I wonder if the code you have wasn't actually made in Inkscape?

Comment: Billy, I think you think I was the person who mposted the question. I know Inkscape can perfectly generate a perfectly well formed circle. But the circle provided in the svg above in the question is wrong. Don't know if it was generated in Inkscape or any other software.

Comment: I do suspect it wasn't generated in Inkscape, and if so, that would mean the problem was not actually caused by Inkscape. It looks like it was opened in Inkscape, then saved as SVG which is why it has all the Inkscape sodipodi elements. But yeah, the code is definitely wrong.